# Adobe photoshop CS6 support XP?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to know does adobe photoshopCS6 supports XP?

or else now which version supports XP for phtoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop CS6 is the last version of photoshop to support XP. Good luck!

Comment: So photoshop cs6 supports xp???

Comment: @Sohail yes, but no versions after this one will support it

Answer (score 0):

The Photoshop team would like to provide advanced notice that Photoshop CS6 (13.0) will be the last major version of Photoshop to support Windows XP. (Photoshop CS6 does not support Windows Vista